# Send CardActions in HeroCard as a welcome message and direct to the respective dialog

Tags: .net-core, botframework

I'm using Dialogs and waterfallstep to organize the dialog logic, and
I want a `HeroCard` with `CardActions` as a welcome message. It works fine just sending a `HeroCard` as a welcome message, but my problem is to direct to the right dialog using `turnContext` when the user click on one of the options in the `CardAction`.

Here's my code in `Bots.WelcomeBot.cs` where I'm stuck. These two methods are after `OnMembersAddedAsync` which works fine.

```
private static async Task MainMenuAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var card = new HeroCard
        {
            Text = "Welcome! What can I help you with?",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = "Contact", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Contact" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Newsletter", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Newsletter" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Products", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Products" },
            },
        };
        var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
        await MainMenuChoisesAsync(turnContext, reply, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static async Task MainMenuChoisesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, IMessageActivity reply, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        string choice = reply.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

        switch (choice) {
            case "contact":
                {
                    //Direct to ContactDialog.cs
                }
        }
    }
```

Originally this menu of options are in my MainDialog which is triggered when the user has written anything in the start of the chat. The next waterfallstep then redirect to the right Dialog.

Comment: What channel are you using (e.g. webchat, facebook etc.) and how do you trigger the welcome message? Are you using the `conversationUpdate` event or a custom event. [read more](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/)

Comment: I'm going to use it in webchat. I just put my bot on a simple html website, then I noticed the simple welcome message doesn't show until the user has written something. I'm using `ConversationUpdate`, the same logic as Microsoft's [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) which works fine in the Emulator with DirectLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you’re using WebChat or directline, the bot’s ConversationUpdate is sent when the conversation is created and the user sides’ ConversationUpdate is sent when they first send a message. When ConversationUpdate is initially sent, there isn’t enough information in the message to construct the dialog stack. The reason that this appears to work in the emulator, is that the emulator simulates a sort of pseudo DirectLine, but both conversationUpdates are resolved at the same time in the emulator, and this is not the case for how the actual service performs.
>   (source: [How to properly send a greeting message and common issues from customers](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/))

Currently it is not possible to use the `conversationUpdate` event for the scenario you describe. You can solve this by sending a custom event when the WebChat is fully loaded, however you can’t use the default iframe provided by the Bot Service. 
Have a look at [implementing the Web Chat v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#how-to-use).

Have a look at a sample which shows how to implement a welcome activity when the bot first starts:

- [WebChat v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) (recommended)
- [WebChat v3](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/)

Comment: If you generate a Direct Line token with a user id for Web Chat, you can send a welcome message from the `conversationUpdate` event in the `onMembersAdded` handler. https://gist.github.com/tdurnford/e01b0bd6431ad9ae6d801f90235fa1d2